# Neovim python host failed after installing Vim and Gvim

Tags: python, vim, neovim

As always we want to try something new and end up messing our configurations! I didn't notice too much difference between Vim and Neovim speed and because Vim has Gvim as a GUI I decided to give Gvim a shot.
Before the full transition I was working on some projects in Neovim. Now when I start it, it complains about python host failed. For sure when installing Vim back it messed some configuration. Any ideas on what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, reinstall neovim with sudo pip2 install neovim solve it!